# How to .save/POST an array of values from a JSON key value pair in Java spring-boot JPA

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to save an object to my database through a REST .POST and when I am receiving the JSON object from the frontend one of the values from a json key has multiple values in an array form.

**JSON:**

```
{ "supportedId": [ 2, 4, 1, 18592, 18594 ], "reportSubscriptionId": 100 }
```

I want to save each "supportedId" as its own INSERT/Unique entry in the database with "reportSubscriptionId: 100" like the json object above.

How do I iterate through the array and save this properly? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
 @RequestMapping(
      method = RequestMethod.POST
      )
@ResponseBody
public ApplicationUserSubscription createAppSubscription(@RequestBody ApplicationUserSubscription appUser) {

  return applicationUserSubscriptionRepository.save(appUser);
```

---

```
@Repository
public interface ApplicationUserSubscriptionRepository extends 
JpaRepository<ApplicationUserSubscription, Integer>  {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create request class to map input and the create entity by processing input request as below,

Entity:

```
public class ApplicationUserSubscription {
    @Id
    private Integer supportedId;
    private Integer reportSubscriptionId;
    //constructor getter setters
```

}

Request:

```
class ApplicationUserSubscriptionRequest {
     private List<Integer> supportedIds;
     private Integer reportSubscriptionId;
     //contructor getter setters
  }
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<ApplicationUserSubscription> createAppSubscription(@RequestBody ApplicationUserSubscriptionRequest applicationUserSubscriptionRequest) {
List<ApplicationUserSubscription> subscriptions = applicationUserSubscriptionRequest.getSupportedIds().stream()
               .map(ele -> new ApplicationUserSubscription(ele, applicationUserSubscriptionRequest.getReportSubscriptionId()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
   return applicationUserSubscriptionRepository.saveAll(subscriptions);
}
```

Repository:

```
 @Repository
 public interface ApplicationUserSubscriptionRepository extends JpaRepository<ApplicationUserSubscription, Integer> {

  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's telling me that The constructor ApplicationUserSubscription(Integer, int) is undefined in the controller. If I do create the constructor I get errors in my repository -Error creating bean with name 'applicationUserSubscriptionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.fedex.ground.fass.shiftReportMod.repository.ApplicationUserSubscriptionRepository.saveAll(java.util.List)! No property saveAll found for type ApplicationUserSubscription!

Comment: I have updated the answer. You are not required to add saveAll method to the repository. I have also changed type to int. It should work now.